# Commenting after a move

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

I commented on [someone else's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/138650/ubuntu-server-or-debian-server-to-run-c-apps-developed-on-ubuntu/138656#138656) on SO.

Then the post was moved to SF, where I don't have the required rep to comment other people's posts.

The answer poster @commented me, but now I'm unable to reply.

IMHO you should be always able to add comments to any post or answer **where you do already have comments**, regardless of reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your profile page on SF, click "accounts", unassociate your accounts and reassociate them. I suppose you didn't have 200 rep on SO when you first associated the accounts. Now that you have enough on SO, associating with that will give you a 100 rep bonus on Server Fault. Then you can comment.

Comment: as long as you have 200 rep *AT THE TIME OF ASSOCIATION* you will get the 100 rep bonus on the target site.